# Which is better "drive to do" vs "drive in doing"

Tags: word-usage

Which is better?

1. to drive to do: "he was driven to choose quickly"
2. to drive in doing: "he was driven in choosing quickly"

Comment: They're different, if subtly so, from the point of view of the tense. The first describes a completed action in the past. The second describes a continuing action in the past that may or may not have been completed.

Answer (score 1):

One is not better than the other because they mean two different things.

The differences:

- *"he was driven to choose quickly"* **implies** that an outside force     made him choose something quickly.
- *"he was driven in choosing quickly"* **implies** that the choosing is what drove him to do something.

Answer (score 0):

Which is better depends on the context you are using it in. 'He was driven to choose' uses 'drive' as a verb and implies an outside force *driving* him *to* choose. 'He was driven in choosing' puts the focus on him and implies that the drive to choose is his own.